# Grouping prefix and term queries

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bigdata, nlp

Consider the following context:

You have a website that is offering a search function, which produces a list of matching articles.

The search has prefix functionality: if you are looking for "Samsung Galaxy", the user can also input "Sams Galax" and he will still get a list of results. Now what you try to find out, how many users are using shortened (prefix-) and how many are using full terms.

As your dataset you have a list of customer-executed queries which also contains a number how many articles were in the produced results. But you have no data which of the resulted articles the users finally clicked on. So you can't easily indicate whether the search was successful or not and what exactly the users were looking for.

How would you analyze the data to split it in the two groups, e.g. prefix- and full-term?